# What are the alternative ways for getting a column having list of column value WITHOUT using collect_list

Tags: group-by, pyspark, aggregate-functions, collect

I'm currently using collect list to achieve this result, but it is taking more time.

```
df= df.groupBy("col1").agg(collect_list(df['col2']).alias('col2'))
```

Input df:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|a   |x   |
|a   |y   |
|b   |y   |
+----+----+
```

Expected Output currently achievable by collect_list but trying to find an alternative way:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|a   |x,y |
|b   |y   |
+----+----+
```

I'm trying to achieve the same using split and join. Something like below which I'm unable to figure out the exact syntax.

```
def list_cols(cols):
    return [','.join(val.split()) for val in cols]
df = df.groupBy('col1').agg(list_cols(meta["cols"]))
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? collect_list/set was specifically written with your use case in mind. What you are doing is only going to make it more inefficient.

Comment: Collect list seem to be costly. Want to try new ways if possible to reduce the execution cost. Using collect list takes about 3 minutes in my machine. I am trying to reduce the time if possible without using collect list.

Comment: @Vincent anything you write yourself will almost surely be more inefficient than using `collect_list`